# Kong http2 on 8000 port

Tags: nginx, grpc, http2, kong

I am working on enabling http2 for our kong app. Enabled http2 on 8000 like this.

KONG_PROXY_LISTEN=0.0.0.0:8000 http2

When I tested grpc service on 8000 port got a valid response but when i try http service on 8000 got following error

```
curl -X POST localhost:8000/httptest
Warning: Binary output can mess up your terminal. Use "--output -" to tell 
Warning: curl to output it to your terminal anyway, or consider "--output 
Warning: <FILE>" to save to a file.
```

Can someone share me if http2 and http need to be enabled on different ports?

Comment: Just add `-v` to get details from curl

Comment: curl -v -X POST localhost:8000
* Rebuilt URL to: localhost:8000/
*   Trying ::1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to localhost (::1) port 8000 (#0)
> POST / HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:8000
> User-Agent: curl/7.58.0
> Accept: */*
> 
Warning: Binary output can mess up your terminal. Use "--output -" to tell 
Warning: curl to output it to your terminal anyway, or consider "--output 
Warning: <FILE>" to save to a file.
* Failed writing body (0 != 57)
* stopped the pause stream!
* Closing connection 0

Comment: AS you can see the call is done on http 1.1, you can use `--http2` to force the use of http2

Comment: Isnt http2 backward compatible and http request should work without forcing it to?

Comment: *   Trying ::1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to localhost (::1) port 8000 (#0)
> POST /httptest HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:8000
> User-Agent: curl/7.58.0
> Accept: */*
> Connection: Upgrade, HTTP2-Settings
> Upgrade: h2c
> HTTP2-Settings: AAMAAABkAARAAAAAAAIAAAAA
> 
Warning: Binary output can mess up your terminal. Use "--output -" to tell 
Warning: curl to output it to your terminal anyway, or consider "--output 
Warning: <FILE>" to save to a file.
* Failed writing body (0 != 57)
* stopped the pause stream!
* Closing connection 0